# Programa em C não faz a leitura correta de um arquivo .txt com números inteiros

Tags: c, c++, string, fopen, inteiros

Estou com esse código em C onde o objetivo é ler 25 números inteiros de um arquivo texto e armazená-los em uma matriz 5 por 5. O problema é que ao executar no MS-DOS, o programa imprime apenas lixos da memória. Creio que seja o `fgets(...)`. Existe alguém comando semelhante para inteiros? Alguém pode ajudar na solução?

Segue trecho do código referente ao problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int matriz_A[5][5];
int matriz_B[3][2];
int matriz_C[3][2];
int m, n;

printf("\n Abaixo temos a matriz A \n\n\n");

FILE *matrizA;
matrizA = fopen("matriz_A.txt", "r");

if (matrizA == NULL)
{
    printf("\nNão foi possivel abrir o arquivo. \n");
    exit(0);
}

while (fgets(matriz_A, 25, matrizA) != NULL);
{
    for (m = 0; m<5; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n<5; n++)
        {
            printf(" %i ", matriz_A[m][n]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Saída depois de executado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A função fgets lê uma string de caracteres até encontrar um final de linha ('\n') ou chegar ao limite da quantidade de caracteres especificado. Se no seu arquivo texto contém números você pode ler diretamente os números com a função fscanf ou ler a string e depois tratar a string, por exemplo com a função sscanf.

Comment: Você pode utilizar dois loops for (m=0; m<5; m++) for (n=0; n<5; n++) fscanf(matrizA, "%d", &matriz_A[m][n]);

Answer (score 1):

Saudações

Você precisará fazer o processo em duas etapas:

1 - Você terá que ler o arquivo e inserir os dados na matriz;

2 - Depois de inserir os dados na matriz ai sim você poder ler

O que está acontecendo é que você está imprimindo ANTES de ter alguma coisa dentro da matriz, o fgets não funciona da forma como vc está pensando!

Você não postou o arquivo de entrada, estou supondo que seja algo mais ou menos assim:

```
10 20 30 40 50
10 20 30 40 50
10 20 30 40 50
10 20 30 40 50
10 20 30 40 50
```

Minha sugestão é a seguinte, primeiro leia as entradas utilizando algo do tipo:

```
FILE *file = fopen ( "matriz_A.txt", "r" );
if ( file == NULL ) {
  printf("Erro ao ler arquivo.");
}
char s[10];
while ( fgets ( s, sizeof s, file ) != NULL ) {
  printf("%s",s);
}
```

No lugar do printf você terá que fazer o tratamento para inserir na posição correta da matriz! Use uma variável auxiliar para ir contando!

Para converter de string para inteiro use a função atoi.

Boa sorte com seu exercício.

Answer (score 1):

### Vejamos...

Considere o arquivo com os dados da matriz arranjado da seguinte forma:

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

... Ou mesmo da seguinte forma:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Se leres os dados do arquivo para a matriz com o algoritmo que segue:

```
for( m = 0; m < 5; m++ ){

    for( n = 0; n < 5; n++ ) fscanf( matrizA, "%d%*c", &matriz_A[m][n] );

    }
```

... Verás que tudo funcionará!

### Explicando

O sub-especificador `*` usado com os especificadores `%` e `c` (formando `%*c`), indica que é para ignorar qualquer tipo de dado do tipo especificado e que está sendo lido. Ou seja, não será armazenado e sim ignorado. Note que a ordem importa e `*` deve vir logo após o especificador `%`.

Considerando que a cada leitura o ponteiro de posição dentro do arquivo não se altera sem o desenvolvedor mandar, tantos os espaços quanto pulos de linha e fim de arquivo são ignorados pelo `fscanf`. O `fscanf` nada mais é que um `scanf` para arquivos.

Se quiseres saber mais sobre especificadores e sub-especificadores no `scanf` e derivados de leitura, leia este artigo da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications). Alternativamente, leia esta explicação sobre o `fscanf` do [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/#parameters). Ambos os textos estão em Inglês.

### Os problemas

Vale a observar a razão dos dados aleatórios apresentados em seu algoritmo:

1. Tipos diferentes entre matriz e dados do arquivo;
2. Um array bidimensional (matriz) difere do tipo necessário para `fgets` (array);
3. Em razão do item 2, o armazenamento dos dados do arquivo se dão de forma errada e caótica, tomando o lugar de endereços da matriz;
4. A impressão de dados de outras parte da memória em razão do item 3;

Tente pensar um pouco sobre os problemas apontados. Se não conseguir entender, faça uma nova pergunta a respeito!